# Реализация сдвига ячеек в игре 2048 на C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу код уже несколько дней и все не решается проблема: при клике либо вообще не появляется ячейка, думаю, проблема в сдвиге, так как если убрать функции сдвига, то ячейки нормально появляются

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int[,] map = new int[4, 4];
        public Label[,] labels = new Label[4, 4];
        public Button[,] but = new Button[4, 4];
        //public static int indexpic = 0;
        private int score = 0;
        bool IsShift = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            createMap();
            createNewPic();
        }

        private void createMap()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    //Button bu = new Button();
                    but[i, j] = new Button();
                    but[i, j].Location = new Point(30 + 58 * j, 73 + 58 * i);
                    but[i, j].Size = new Size(50, 50);
                    but[i, j].BackColor = Color.Gray;
                    but[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(Click1);
                    this.Controls.Add(but[i, j]);
                    map[i, j] = 0;
                }
            }
            return;
        }

        private void createNewPic()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int i = rnd.Next(0, 3);
            int j = rnd.Next(0, 3);
            map[i, j] = 1;
            but[i, j] = new Button();
            labels[i, j] = new Label();
            labels[i, j].Text = "2";
            labels[i, j].Size = new Size(50, 50);
            labels[i, j].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            but[i, j].Font = new Font(new FontFamily("Microsoft Sans Serif"), 15);
            but[i, j].Controls.Add(labels[i, j]);
            but[i, j].Location = new Point(30 + j * 58, 73 + 58 * i);
            but[i, j].Size = new Size(50, 50);
            but[i, j].BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
            this.Controls.Add(but[i, j]);
            but[i, j].BringToFront();
        }

        private void ColorOfBut(int sum, int i, int j)
        {
            if (sum / 2048 == 1) but[i, j].BackColor = Color.Green;
            else if (sum / 1024 == 1) but[i, j].BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
            else if (sum / 512 == 1) but[i, j].BackColor = Color.Sienna;
            else if (sum / 256 == 1) but[i, j].BackColor = Color.DarkViolet;
            else if (sum / 128 == 1) but[i, j].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            else if (sum / 64 == 1) but[i, j].BackColor = Color.Red;
            else if (sum / 32 == 1) but[i, j].BackColor = Color.Pink;
            else if (sum / 16 == 1) but[i, j].BackColor = Color.Coral;
            else if (sum / 8 == 1) but[i, j].BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
            else if (sum / 4 == 1) but[i, j].BackColor = Color.LightPink;
        }

        #region Функции сдвигов
        private void RightShift()
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {
                for (int l = 2; l >= 0; l--)
                {
                    if (map[k, l] == 1)
                    {
                        for (int j = l + 1; j < 4; j++)
                        {
                            if (map[k, j] == 0)//&& j<4)
                            {
                                map[k, j - 1] = 0;
                                map[k, j] = 1;
                                but[k, j] = but[k, j - 1];
                                but[k, j - 1] = null;
                                labels[k, j] = labels[k, j - 1];
                                labels[k, j - 1] = null;
                                but[k, j].Location = new Point(but[k, j].Location.X + 58, but[k, j].Location.Y);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                int a = int.Parse(labels[k, j].Text);
                                int b = int.Parse(labels[k, j - 1].Text);
                                if (a == b)
                                {
                                    labels[k, j].Text = (a + b).ToString();
                                    score += (a + b);
                                    //map[k, j] = 1;
                                    label1.Text = "Очки: " + score;
                                    ColorOfBut(a + b, k, j);
                                    map[k, j - 1] = 0;
                                    //this.Controls.Remove(but[k, j - 1]);
                                    //this.Controls.Remove(labels[k, j - 1]);
                                    but[k, j - 1] = null;
                                    labels[k, j - 1] = null;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void LeftShift()
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {
                for (int l = 1; l < 4; l++)
                {
                    if (map[k, l] == 1)
                    {
                        for (int j = l - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                        {
                            if (map[k, j] == 0)
                            {
                                map[k, j + 1] = 0;
                                map[k, j] = 1;
                                but[k, j] = but[k, j + 1];
                                but[k, j + 1] = null;
                                labels[k, j] = labels[k, j + 1];
                                labels[k, j + 1] = null;
                                but[k, j].Location = new Point(but[k, j].Location.X - 58, but[k, j].Location.Y);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                int a = int.Parse(labels[k, j].Text);
                                int b = int.Parse(labels[k, j + 1].Text);
                                if (a == b)
                                {
                                    labels[k, j].Text = (a + b).ToString();
                                    map[k, j] = 1;
                                    score += (a + b);
                                    label1.Text = "Очки: " + score;
                                    ColorOfBut(a + b, k, j);
                                    map[k, j + 1] = 0;
                                    this.Controls.Remove(but[k, j + 1]);
                                    this.Controls.Remove(labels[k, j + 1]);
                                    but[k, j + 1] = null;
                                    labels[k, j + 1] = null;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void DownShift()
        {
            for (int k = 2; k >= 0; k--)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++)
                {
                    if (map[k, l] == 1)
                    {
                        for (int j = k + 1; j < 4; j++)
                        {
                            if (map[j, l] == 0)
                            {
                                map[j - 1, l] = 0;
                                map[j, l] = 1;
                                but[j, l] = but[j - 1, l];
                                but[j - 1, l] = null;
                                labels[j, l] = labels[j - 1, l];
                                labels[j - 1, l] = null;
                                but[j, l].Location = new Point(but[j, l].Location.X, but[j, l].Location.Y + 58);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                int a = int.Parse(labels[j, l].Text);
                                int b = int.Parse(labels[j - 1, l].Text);
                                if (a == b)
                                {
                                    labels[j, l].Text = (a + b).ToString();
                                    score += (a + b);
                                    label1.Text = "Очки: " + score;
                                    ColorOfBut(a + b, j, l);
                                    map[j - 1, l] = 0;
                                    map[k, j] = 1;
                                    this.Controls.Remove(but[j - 1, l]);
                                    this.Controls.Remove(labels[j - 1, l]);
                                    but[j - 1, l] = null;
                                    labels[j - 1, l] = null;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        private void UpShift()
        {
            for (int k = 1; k < 4; k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++)
                {
                    if (map[k, l] == 1)
                    {
                        for (int j = k - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                        {
                            if (map[j, l] == 0)
                            {
                                map[j + 1, l] = 0;
                                map[j, l] = 1;
                                but[j, l] = but[j + 1, l];
                                but[j + 1, l] = null;
                                labels[j, l] = labels[j + 1, l];
                                labels[j + 1, l] = null;
                                but[j, l].Location = new Point(but[j, l].Location.X, but[j, l].Location.Y - 58);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                int a = int.Parse(labels[j, l].Text);
                                int b = int.Parse(labels[j + 1, l].Text);
                                if (a == b)
                                {
                                    labels[j, l].Text = (a + b).ToString();
                                    map[j, l] = 1;
                                    score += (a + b);
                                    ColorOfBut(a + b, j, l);
                                    label1.Text = "Очки: " + score;
                                    map[j + 1, l] = 0;
                                    this.Controls.Remove(but[j + 1, l]);
                                    this.Controls.Remove(labels[j + 1, l]);
                                    but[j + 1, l] = null;
                                    labels[j + 1, l] = null;
                                }
                            }
                            //if (labels[j, l].Text == "2048") MessageBox.Show("Игра окончена! Вы выиграли!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        private void Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (int m = 0; m < 4; m++)
                {
                    if ((Button)sender == but[i, m])
                    {
                        but[i, m] = new Button();
                        labels[i, m] = new Label();
                        labels[i, m].Text = "2";
                        labels[i, m].Size = new Size(50, 50);
                        labels[i, m].TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                        labels[i, m].Font = new Font(new FontFamily("Microsoft Sans Serif"), 15);
                        but[i, m].Controls.Add(labels[i, m]);
                        but[i, m].Location = new Point(30 + m * 58, 73 + 58 * i);
                        but[i, m].Size = new Size(50, 50);
                        but[i, m].BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
                        map[i, m] = 1;
                        UpShift();
                        this.Controls.Add(but[i, m]);
                        UpShift();
                        but[i, m].BringToFront();
                        //ClickShift();

                        //break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        private void ClickShift()
        {
            bool Shift = false;
            Refresh();
            do
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                {
                    for (int j = 2; j >= 0; j--)
                    {
                        if (map[k, j] == map[k, j + 1] || map[k, j] != 0 && map[k, j + 1] == 0)
                        {
                            RightShift();
                            Shift = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            for (int f = 1; f < 4; f++)
                            {
                                for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++)
                                {
                                    if (map[f, k] == map[f - 1, k] || map[f, k] != 0 && map[f - 1, k] == 0)
                                    {
                                        UpShift();
                                        Shift = true;
                                        break;
                                    }

                                    else
                                    {
                                        for (int s = 1; s < 4; s++)
                                        {
                                            if (map[k, f] == map[k, f - 1] || map[k, f] == 1 && map[k, f - 1] == 0)
                                            {
                                                LeftShift();
                                                Shift = true;
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                if (map[j, k] == map[j + 1, k] || map[j, k] == 1 && map[j + 1, k] == 0)
                                                {
                                                    DownShift();
                                                    Shift = true;
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } while (Shift = true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Начните с того, что вам не нужны кнопки, достаточно просто `Label` фиксированного размера с фоном. Потом, попробуйте реализовать для начала без анимации. Управление игрой стрелками с клавиатуры. Как удастся добиться простоты и понятности в коде, приступайте к анимациям. Потом, при выборе цвета, зачем вам деление, если можно просто сверить значение с константой, и там можно `switch-case`.

Comment: просто у меня задача состоит в том, что пользователь сам выбирает, где появится новая ячейка, цифра, а программа сдвигает и складывает их. Должно что-то подобное быть: https://sphere.chronosempire.org.uk/~HEx/8402/

Comment: А проблему сдвига смотрите в отладчике, с ходу не понять, возможно бесконечный цикл, или значения улетают за пределы игрового поля.

Comment: Если я буду сам выбирать, где появится новая двойка, я буду выигрывать с вероятностью 100%. Эта игра уже не 2048 получится, а что-то другое. Я давал вам советы исходя из классических правил.

Comment: Еще важный совет. Никогда на вставляйте свой код в конструктор формы. Используйте обработчик события `Form.Load` вместо этого. В противном случае вы можете поломать приложение и так и не найти, почему не работает.

Answer (score 2):

`while (Shift = true)` это бесконечный цикл, потому что здесь не сравнение, а присваивание+сравнение. Д.б. `while (Shift)`

Comment: Кстати, мелкомягкие недавно выпустили студию 2019 16.6, в которой анализатор кода начал ловить этот случай и выдавать предупреждение. Даже не прошло и 20 лет с момента появления этой проблемы. :)